# How to resize a folder name area in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: icons, directory, resize, filename

I am having folders on my desktop. The folders names exceed the folders icons. So that makes me difficult to read the folder names whenever I align all folders in a same line. What I want is to re-size the folders name area to make it readable. Is it possible?

P.S: The same requested for the file names also.

Answer (score 3):

### **Horizontal Adjustment: Overlapping icons**

If this is your first experience with Ubuntu, you might have noticed that icons can be arranged in a way where their file names are overlapping.

[image: overlapping icons]

This is not an error, [it's a wanted behavior](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/40872). The user should not be limited in the ways, he can arrange his icons. If he wants the icons to overlap, he should be able to do so.

What you expected is a "snap to grid"-like functionality like you might know from other operating systems. In Ubuntu you are free to place your icons where you want to place them and lock the arrangement. You might call that "lock to place" instead of "lock to grid".

This means you just have to move the icons until they do not overlap anymore. When you are happy with your arrangement, `right-click` to open the context menu and choose to `lock the arrangement`.

[image: perfectly aligned icons]

### **Vertical Adjustment: Change the number of displayed lines of icon text**

[image: Change the number of displayed lines of icon text]

**- Install dconf-tools**

Open up a terminal with `CTRL+ALT+T` and install dconf-tools with:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

**- Change nautilus configuration**

Start the dconf editor with the command:

`dconf-editor`

Then navigate through `/org/gnome/nautilus/desktop` and change the value for the field-key

`text-ellipsis-limit` to 0 (if you don't want your file names to be truncated)

or insert a value x > 0 for displaying up to x  lines of the file name.

**- Restart nautilus**

`nautilus -q` and then open a file-manager window to start nautilus again.

### **Icon Adjustments: Change details displayed in the icon text**

Open a file-manager window and go to `Edit -> Settings` in the menu. In the `Display Tab` you can choose which additional should be displayed when the zoom level (`Views Tab`) is increased. If you choose `None`, only the name of the folder or file will be displayed.

See the [Nautilus Documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/gosnautilus-439.html.en) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But my problem still consists. Is it possible because of that I am using unity desktop?

Comment: I added a picture to show what is done by the configuration edit i showed above. The change affects nautilus, the default file-manager for ubuntu. Or did you try to achieve something different?

Comment: Folder name's length should appear as much as folder icon's size at maximum on my desktop. If it a long name then should continue on a second line bottom that do not exceeds the icon's size. By the way at the end of each icon's name it explains the icon's type. For example if it is a folder it says "folder" if it as an "image" it says "GIMP image" etc. I would like these extra information disappear too. Actually I wanted to send you a picture of my desktop but I don't know how to send it here. Thank you very much for your assistance. Piremerd.

Comment: It is exactly as shown in your picture but the given file name should not exceed the file icon's size.

Comment: You can increase the default zoom level for your icons. Open a file-manager window, go to `Edit->Preferences` and play with the default values for the icon view in the `Views` tab. In the `Display` tab you can set the additional details that should be displayed after increasing the zoom level.

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm here to help, but did my last comment help you to solve your problem? BTW, you can upload images to imgur.com and post the link to it here, no need to embed it with an img tag, if that doesn't work (you may need more reputation to do that).

Comment: Actually it did helped me. But not exactly as I wanted. Please check the picture >> imgur.com/QS0xD << My current desktop still as it appears in the picture. The icons names mixed up with each other and if an icon is a folder at the end of the icon's name it describes that is a folder and if it an image it describes that is an image that are not necessary for me to shown up. Again thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. It is possible to arrange the icons as you can [see here](http://imgur.com/LtMJ3). Just move them until they don't overlap anymore and then click on the desktop and choose to lock the arrangement. Unfortunately, only the "lock icons on place" strategy is supported. What you might expect because of earlier experiences is a "snap/lock to grid" feature like in windows, where it's not possible to overlap icons. It seems to be  considered as additional freedom to let the user choose overlapping icons, if he wants them. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is your problem solved (or do you now understand how to arrange icons on your desktop) after my last edit?

Comment: just to add, this solution works on 13.04 as well